# Has anyone experience a stackoverflow exception when updating TextDecorators in InitializeDecorators in DSL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, dsl

I'm having an issue trying to implement this code in DSL.

```
 protected override void InitializeDecorators(IList<ShapeField> shapeFields, IList<Decorator> decorators)
    {
        base.InitializeDecorators(shapeFields, decorators);

        var nameField = (TextField)ShapeElement.FindShapeField(shapeFields, "NameDecorator");

        if (nameField != null)
        {
            nameField.DefaultMultipleLine = true;
            nameField.DefaultAutoSize = false;

            nameField.AnchoringBehavior.Clear();
            nameField.AnchoringBehavior.SetLeftAnchor(AnchoringBehavior.Edge.Left, 0);
            nameField.AnchoringBehavior.SetRightAnchor(AnchoringBehavior.Edge.Right, 0);
            nameField.AnchoringBehavior.SetTopAnchor(nameField, AnchoringBehavior.Edge.Top, 0);
            nameField.AnchoringBehavior.SetBottomAnchor(AnchoringBehavior.Edge.Bottom, 0);
        }
    }
```

This is basically copied and pasted from the Microsoft docs located here:

[ShapeField.AnchoringBehavior Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.modeling.diagrams.shapefield.anchoringbehavior.aspx)

I have tried this both in my solution and the minimal language version supplied as a template in Visual Studio, with no other customization except for including the above code.

It seems to be happening in generated code in **DomainClasses.cs** in the following **NamePropertyHandler** class in the following method on the return:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Gets a strongly-typed value of the property on specified element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element">Element which owns the property.</param>
        /// <returns>Property value.</returns>
        public override sealed global::System.String GetValue(BaseActivityBase element)
        {
            if (element == null) throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("element");
            return element.namePropertyStorage;
        }
```

I am stumped and since this is happening in both the minimal language version and my own I have a feeling something bigger is going on.

Has anyone else had any issues with this, and maybe has a workaround or something?

Comment: A key difference between the example you've linked to and your code is that the example seems to be working with two separate fields. In your case, you're trying to work with one field. Which makes me suspect that `nameField.AnchoringBehavior.SetTopAnchor(nameField, AnchoringBehavior.Edge.Top, 0);` is going to be implicated somewhere in here.

Comment: You know what thanks Damien I think the use of the overload passing the namefield in the anchor behaviour is the cause, I didn't notice that, nice to have another pair of eyes... I'll give it look and get back

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my copy paste stupidity... the overload where I was passing the name was causing a recursive issue.

```
nameField.AnchoringBehavior.SetTopAnchor(nameField, AnchoringBehavior.Edge.Top, 0);
```

and should be

```
    nameField.AnchoringBehavior.SetTopAnchor(AnchoringBehavior.Edge.Top, 0);
```